# Calculate the best possible combination of items within a cost and weight limit

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to help my sister with a college assignment in Computer programming(I'm in the Irish equivalent of High School). I've programmed in Python and Java before but seldom C. The project has to be done in C.

Essentially, you are given a number of items. Each item has a weight, value and cost. The idea is to calculate the best possible value for the items while staying within a weight limit and budget.

I've written a code, but it doesn't work. Each time it is run the output is a random array of numbers and the weight and cost values are zero...

I think the problem is to do with the realloc function, but I don't know how to use that probably. I essentially want to make an array that I can change the length of. I don't think realloc is designed for this... Any advice or solutions would be a great help...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check(int finalList[], int value, int current,int limit, int weight, int tempw, int budget, int cost, int tempc, int Clist[], int x);

int main()
{
    int nlist[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int values[5] = {4,5,7,2,9};
    int weights[5] = {1,4,8,2,9};
    int costs[5]= {3,6,2,1,8};
    int n = 5;
    int x,i,j,k,l,m,p=0;
    int value=0, cost= 0, weight = 0,tempv=0, tempw = 0, tempc = 0;
    int budget = 45;
    int limit = 12;
    int finalList[n];

    for(x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        { 
            int list[x+1];
            list[0] = nlist[i];
            tempv = values[i];
            tempw = weights[i];
            tempc = costs[i];

            for(j=0;j<x;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                {
                    list[0]=nlist[i];
                    tempv = values[i];
                    tempw = weights[i];
                    tempc = costs[i];
                    m = p;

                    for(l=0;l<x;l++)
                    {
                        if(m==i)
                        {
                            m++;
                            p++;
                        }

                        list[l] = nlist[m];
                        tempv = tempv + values[m];
                        tempw = tempw + weights[m];
                        tempc = tempc + costs[m];
                        check(finalList, value,tempv, limit, weight, tempw, budget, cost, tempc, list,x);
                    }

                    p++;
                }
            }
            check(finalList, value,tempv,limit, weight, tempw, budget, cost, tempc, list,x);
        }
    }

    printf("\nMost efficient item list:" );
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d", finalList[i]);
    }
    printf("\nWeight: %d", weight);
    printf("\nCost: %d", cost);
}


int check(int finalList[], int value, int current,int limit, int weight, int tempw, int budget, int cost, int tempc, int Clist[], int x)
{
    if(tempw<=limit)
    {
        if(tempc<=budget)
        {
            if (current>value)
            {
                finalList = realloc(finalList, 1*(x+1));
                finalList= Clist;
                value = current;
                weight = tempw;
                cost = tempc;
            }

        }
    }
    return finalList,value,weight,cost;
}
```

Comment: This isn't much clear. Are you trying to get a subset from the list which value is to maximize being within the bound of the budget and weight?

Comment: Can you explain in more details (maybe with an example) what you're trying to calculate ? Because "the best possible value for the items while staying within a weight limit and budget" does not tell us much about the algorithm needed.

Comment: google: 0-1 knapsack and see if it helps and related to your problem.

Comment: `return finalList,value,weight,cost;` is strange. You should learn how to pass data between functions.

Comment: @JérômeRadix For example:

Comment: @JérômeRadix For example: if you were to have a number of items one combinations could be : Item1(V=1, W= 2, C= 6) & Item2(V=7, W=6, C=30) & Item3(V=7, W=6, C =4). This gives a value of 14 within a weight limit of 13 kg and within a cost of 40. But say the cost limit was 60. A better combination would be Item4(V=8, W= 1, C= 10) & Item3(V=7, W=6, C=4) & Item5(V=5, W=1, C =15) & Item2(V=7, W=6, C =30). This gives a total value of 26, weight of 13kg and a cost of 59. The second combination is better as it has a higher value while staying within the weight and cost limits...

Comment: @MikeCat What do you mean?

Comment: @silentboy Yes, I am trying to get a subset with the best possible value while remaining within the cost and budget values

Comment: @C.Begley This statement is equivalent to `return cost;` and the `finalList,value,weight` do nothing. For that reason, it is a strange statement. Returning something and not using it is also a bit strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll try to show you how object oriented principles with appropriate data structures and small functions can help make code more readable and errors easier to spot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int MAX_COST = 45;
const int MAX_WEIGHT = 12;

const int VALUES[5] = {4, 5, 7, 2, 9};
const int WEIGHTS[5] = {1, 4, 8, 2, 9};
const int COSTS[5] = {3, 6, 2, 1, 8};

typedef struct
{
    // total over all items in the subset
    int value;
    int weight;
    int cost;

    // subset of items
    int indices[5];
    int num_indices;
} candidate;

void candidate_init (candidate *c)
{
    c->value = 0;
    c->weight = 0;
    c->cost = 0;
    c->num_indices = 0;
}

void candidate_print (const candidate *c)
{
    printf ("items:  ");
    for (int i = 0; i < c->num_indices; i++) {
        printf ("%d, ", c->indices[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    printf ("value:  %d\n", c->value);
    printf ("weight: %d\n", c->weight);
    printf ("cost:   %d\n", c->cost);
};

void candidate_add_item (candidate *c, int i)
{
    c->value += VALUES[i];
    c->weight += WEIGHTS[i];
    c->cost += COSTS[i];

    c->indices[c->num_indices++] = i;
}

int candidate_is_ok (const candidate *c)
{
    return ((c->weight <= MAX_WEIGHT) && (c->cost <= MAX_COST));
}
```

You don't need dynamic allocation since the number of items is known at compile time.

```
candidate candidates[32]; // 32 == pow (2, 5)
int num_candidates = 0;

void candidates_insert (candidate *c)
{
    candidates[num_candidates++] = *c;
}
```

And now the main code, which should be easy to understand:

```
int main ()
{
    // insert empty candidate                                                   
    {
        candidate c;
        candidate_init (&c);
        candidates_insert (&c);
    }

    // generate all valid candidates                                            
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int n = num_candidates;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            candidate c = candidates[j];
            candidate_add_item (&c, i);
            if (candidate_is_ok (&c)) {
                candidates_insert (&c);
            }
        }
    }

    // find candidate with maximum value                                        
    int max_value = 0;
    int max_i = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_candidates; i++) {
        if (candidates[i].value > max_value) {
            max_value = candidates[i].value;
            max_i = i;
        }
    }

    // print solution                                                           
    candidate_print (&candidates[max_i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just one thing, what does -> mean. My compiler(CodeBlocks) wouldn't compile that and it gives the error: line 34:                                                                                                                 "'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in c99 mode. Note: use option -std=c99 or -stdgnu99 to complie your code ".                                                                                                              Do you know what that means?

Comment: Does -> refer to a pointer?. I tried replacing c-> with (*c). but that didn't work. What else could I use instead of -> ?

Comment: Ok, so I replace simply declared I before lint 34 and that fixed that error. Now, I get the error @indefined reference to WinMain@16. Any idea what that means?

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't realise that other code block was part of the full code. THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

In the function `check()`:

- You are throwing away the values of `finalList`, `value`, `weight`.
- `return finalList,value,weight,cost;` is equivalent to `return cost;`
- The value of `cost` is also thrown away because the return value is not used.

Using pointers is one way to pass multiple informations between functions.

Also, `m` became too big and `nlist[m]` etc. were causing out-of-range access.

Not knowing about the calculation, this code is at least printing something not zero without crushing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void check(int **finalList, int *value, int current,int limit, int *weight, int tempw, int budget, int *cost, int tempc, int Clist[], int x);

int main(void)
{
    int nlist[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int values[5] = {4,5,7,2,9};
    int weights[5] = {1,4,8,2,9};
    int costs[5]= {3,6,2,1,8};
    int n = 5;
    int x,i,j,k,l,m,p=0;
    int value=0, cost= 0, weight = 0,tempv=0, tempw = 0, tempc = 0;
    int budget = 45;
    int limit = 12;
    int *finalList = calloc(n, sizeof(int));

    for(x=0;x<n;x++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        { 
            int list[x+1];
            for(j=0;j<=x;j++) list[j] = 0; /* initialize the list */
            list[0] = nlist[i];
            tempv = values[i];
            tempw = weights[i];
            tempc = costs[i];

            for(j=0;j<x;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<n;k++)
                {
                    list[0]=nlist[i];
                    tempv = values[i];
                    tempw = weights[i];
                    tempc = costs[i];
                    m = p;

                    for(l=0;l<x;l++)
                    {
                        if(m==i)
                        {
                            m++;
                            p++;
                        }

                        if(m<5)
                        {
                            list[l] = nlist[m];
                            tempv = tempv + values[m];
                            tempw = tempw + weights[m];
                            tempc = tempc + costs[m];
                        }
                        check(&finalList, &value,tempv, limit, &weight, tempw, budget, &cost, tempc, list,x);
                    }

                    p++;
                }
            }
            check(&finalList, &value,tempv,limit, &weight, tempw, budget, &cost, tempc, list,x);
        }
    }

    printf("\nMost efficient item list:" );
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d", finalList[i]);
    }
    printf("\nWeight: %d", weight);
    printf("\nCost: %d", cost);
    free(finalList);
    return 0;
}


void check(int **finalList, int *value, int current,int limit, int *weight, int tempw, int budget, int *cost, int tempc, int Clist[], int x)
{
    if(tempw<=limit)
    {
        if(tempc<=budget)
        {
            if (current>*value)
            {
                *finalList = realloc(*finalList, sizeof(int)*(x+1));
                if(*finalList == 0)
                {
                    perror("realloc");
                    exit(1);
                }
                memcpy(*finalList, Clist, sizeof(int)*(x+1));
                *value = current;
                *weight = tempw;
                *cost = tempc;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, the item list at the end is a load of random numbers instead of the array of the optimal list... Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Ok, it's a pointer. But my compiler won't let me use that. Is there another way to notate it ?

Comment: I tried replacing it with (*c). but that didn't work. Is there any other way to replace it?